# New-AdUser : The specified account already exists

Tags: powershell, users, import, bulk

I am trying to import some AD Users using a powershell script and a file.csv but I am getting this error:

`New-AdUser : The specified account already exists`

Here is the script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\userslist.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{  
    $OU = "OU=pfsense,DC=tech,DC=local"  
    $Password = $User.password 
    $Detailedname = $User.firstname + " " + $User.name 
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname 
    $FirstLetterFirstname = $UserFirstname.substring(0,1) 
    $SAM =  $FirstLetterFirstname + $User.name 
    New-ADUser -Name $Detailedname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $SAM -DisplayName $Detailedname -GivenName $user.firstname -Surname $user.name -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path $OU  
}
```

Here is the CSV file:

```
Name;Firstname;Password
MILLE;Thierry;P@$$w0rd!1
MILLE;Vendelin;P@$$w0rd!2
MILLE;Blandine;P@$$w0rd!3
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Find and delete or change the existing account. The error is telling you that this person is ALREADY IN Active Directory.

Comment: no the active Directory was clean when I was trying to run this script.

Comment: Check it again. The error clearly says "The specified account already exists". Look in a different OU. User objects must be unique across the domain, not just within an OU.

Comment: That `$SAM` doesn't really look like a UPN to me. Dunno if that matters though, AD might be able to handle it. Have no way of trying it myself at the moment.

Comment: I also think you should fix the value for upn to someting like `"$($SAM)@domain.local"`. When you run this script, is any user created or none?

Comment: the users are been created but the script is also generating some errors. can you run the script on your own system and see whats happening?

Comment: "exception calling substring with 2 argument(s) index and length must refer to a location within the string".     "New-AdUser : The specified account already exists".

Answer (score 0):

Looking closer at your script, it looks like you might have fat fingered the input for $FirstLetterFirstname. You'll want to add the dot in for $User**[dot]**Firstname.substring(0,1)

```
$FirstLetterFirstname = $User.Firstname.substring(0,1)
```

You might also want to add your domain to the UserPrincipalName

```
-UserPrincipalName $SAM + "@EXAMPLE.com"
```

Comment: This is happening while the users are successfully been imported to the OU so the script is not failing but it just displays that red error massage during the import.